# LWC- Show Hide the Div tag in Template for Each

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I have a custom LWC page which has  table.

In Column one has a `Date` and Column two has three Input fields and `add` and `Delete` button in Column 2.

May 04th `Input box type=number` `add Button` `Delete button`  
May 05th `Input box type=number` `add Button` `Delete button`  
May 05th `Input box type=number` `add Button` `Delete button`

By Clicking the Add button New Row will be Created under  like Below

May 04th `Input box type=number` `add Button` `Delete button` 
                         `Input box type=number` `add Button` `Delete button`

Now i have an anther New Button `add Description` next to `add Button` on click of that I need to show the text area for the Particular Row and display the value from `description` below JSON object

May 04th `Input box type=number` `add Button`  `add Description`  `Delete button` 
                                                                    `Text Area` 
                         `Input box type=number` `add Button`  `add Description`  `Delete button`

`onclick={showDescription}` How we can show/ hide the below Text area for the particular Row.

Below Code show only the First Row, when i click on other Rows, the First row data only shows, not the respective one

```
const addclassName = this.template.querySelector(
      '[data-tsdayindex="' + timesheetdayIndexId + '"]' &&
        '[data-textareakey="' + timesheetdetailIndexId + '"]'
    );
    // alert(addclassName.className);
    if (addclassName.className === "slds-show") {
      addclassName.className = "slds-hide";
    } else {
      addclassName.className = "slds-show";
    }
```

```
   <div key={tsdtl.timesheetDetailIndex} class="slds-large-size_12-of-12 slds-small-size_12-of-12">
        <lightning-textarea value={tsdtl.description} name="timesheetDesc" label="" placeholder="Timesheet Description">
        </lightning-textarea>
    </div>
```

I gone through the `SLDS visibility` utilities, we have `class="slds-hide"` and `class="slds-show"`, But not sure how we have achieve this in iteration, Please Help me on this.

**JSON**

```
[
    {
        "indexVal": 0,
        "timeSheetDate": "May 11th Mon",
        "timeSheetDateId": "a3P1I000000YAPKUA4",
        "timesheetDetails": [
            {
                "description": "Sample Text are Description",
                "projectId": "a071I00005q0dI5QAI",
                "projectName": "Payroll",
                "timeSheetDetailID": "a3O1I000002IEIZUA4",
                "timesheetDetailIndex": 0,
                "timeSheetHours": 5,
                "timeSheetHoursType": "Regular"
            }
        ],
        "timeSheetId": "a2f1I000000frnwQAA",
        "timeSheetUnformatDate": "2020-05-11"
    },
    {
        "indexVal": 1,
        "timeSheetDate": "May 12th Tue",
        "timeSheetDateId": "a3P1I000000YAPLUA4",
        "timesheetDetails": [
            {
                "projectId": "a071I00005q0dI5QAI",
                "projectName": "Payroll",
                "timeSheetDetailID": "a3O1I000002IEIaUAO",
                "timesheetDetailIndex": 1,
                "timeSheetHours": 4,
                "timeSheetHoursType": "Regular"
            }
        ],
        "timeSheetId": "a2f1I000000frnwQAA",
        "timeSheetUnformatDate": "2020-05-12"
    } 
]
```

```
<table
                                class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered slds-border_left slds-border_right"
                                style="width: 80%;">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="">
                                        <th class="" style="background: #03A9F4;" scope="col">
                                            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-truncate slds-text-color_inverse"
                                                style="font-size: initial;" title="Time Sheet Date">
                                                Time Sheet Date</div>
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="" style="background: #03A9F4;" scope="col">
                                            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-truncate slds-text-color_inverse"
                                                style="font-size: initial;" title="Regular">Time Sheet
                                                Details
                                            </div>
                                        </th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <template for:each={timesheetDaysData} for:item="tsd" for:index="index">
                                        <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={tsd.indexVal}>
                                            <th data-label={tsd.timeSheetDate} scope="row">
                                                <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-truncate"
                                                    title={tsd.timeSheetDate} data-id={tsd.timeSheetId}>
                                                    {tsd.timeSheetDate}
                                                </div>
                                            </th>
                                            <td data-label="Time Sheet Details" data-id={tsd.indexVal}>


                                                <div class="demo-only demo-only--sizing slds-grid slds-wrap">


                                                    <template for:each={tsd.timesheetDetails} for:item="tsdtl"
                                                        for:index="index">


                                                        <div class="slds-large-size_2-of-12 slds-small-size_12-of-12 slds-p-left_x-small"
                                                            key={tsdtl.timesheetDetailIndex}>

                                                            <lightning-input type="number"
                                                                data-projectname={tsdtl.projectName} name="hours"
                                                                data-hourstype={tsdtl.timeSheetHoursType}
                                                                data-hours={tsdtl.timeSheetHours}
                                                                value={tsdtl.timeSheetHours}
                                                                data-tsdayindex={tsd.indexVal}
                                                                data-tsdetailindex={tsdtl.timesheetDetailIndex}
                                                                placeholder="Hours" onfocusout={handleOnfocusOutSave}
                                                                onchange={handleChange} label="">
                                                            </lightning-input>

                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="slds-large-size_2-of-12 slds-small-size_12-of-12 slds-p-left_x-small slds-p-top_large"
                                                            key={tsdtl.timesheetDetailIndex}>

                                                            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:add"
                                                                data-id={tsd.indexVal} alternative-text="Add"
                                                                title="Add TimeSheet Details" variant="success"
                                                                onclick={addNewTimeDetails} size="x-small">
                                                            </lightning-icon>
                                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:description"
                                                                data-tsdid={tsdtl.timeSheetDetailID}
                                                                data-id={tsdtl.timesheetDetailIndex}
                                                                data-tsdayindex={tsd.indexVal}
                                                                alternative-text="Description" title="Add Description" onclick={showDescription}
                                                                variant="warning" size="x-small">
                                                            </lightning-icon>
                                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:delete"
                                                                data-tsdid={tsdtl.timeSheetDetailID}
                                                                data-id={tsdtl.timesheetDetailIndex}
                                                                data-tsdayindex={tsd.indexVal} alternative-text="Delete"
                                                                title="Delete TimeSheet Details" variant="error"
                                                                onclick={removeTimeSheetDetails} size="x-small">
                                                            </lightning-icon>

                                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;

                                                        </div>


                                                        <!-- </div> -->
                                                        <!-- slds-hide -->

                                                        <div key={tsdtl.timesheetDetailIndex}
                                                            class="slds-large-size_12-of-12 slds-small-size_12-of-12">
                                                            <lightning-textarea value={tsdtl.description}
                                                                name="timesheetDesc" label=""
                                                                placeholder="Timesheet Description">
                                                            </lightning-textarea>
                                                        </div>


                                                    </template>
                                                </div>


                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                    </template>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to change all your `lightning-icon` to be a `lightning-button-icon` if you want them to be actionable.

Then, add the row id to your text-area so that it can be identified:

```
<lightning-textarea
   value={tsdtl.description}
   name="timesheetDesc"
   placeholder="Timesheet Description"
   data-id={tsdtl.timesheetDetailIndex}
>
```

Then, write the next handler:

```
toggleDescription(event) {
    const rowId = event.target.dataset.id;
    this.template.querySelector(`lightning-textarea[data-id="${rowId}"]`).classList.toggle('slds-hide');
}
```

Note I changed the name of the handler to `toggleDescription`.

**Additional recommendation:** I've posted here the simplest solution, however I recommend you to refactor your code to have a single `div` enclosing all the contents for a row. Add the `key` and the `data-id` attributes to that `div` only. Then you can find the child elements using CSS. In the example: `div[data-id="${rowId}"] lightning-textarea`

Comment: Alba, When i click of second row plus button or third Row Plus button, It shows on First Row not to the respective Row. Below is the Code.

   `const addclassName = this.template.querySelector(
      '[data-tsdayindex="' + timesheetdayIndexId + '"]' &&
        '[data-textareakey="' + timesheetdetailIndexId + '"]'
    );
    // alert(addclassName.className);
    if (addclassName.className === "slds-show") {
      addclassName.className = "slds-hide";
    } else {
      addclassName.className = "slds-show";
    }`

Comment: I checked again and my implementation - which is slightly different than yours - is working fine with several rows. Can you simplify the CSS selector? I don't think you need to use tsdayindex and textareakey - just use one id to identify every single row, and use CSS to look for the child elements. Another detail is you just need to toggle the class.